# activeadmin one to one association not saving id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Why is the associated record id not saved?

[Diagram of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz5gd.png)
[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fn2l.png)

[image: Activeadmin screenshot]

**Teacher Migration**

```
class CreateTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teachers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :classroom
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Classrooms migration**

```
class CreateClassrooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :classrooms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**model/teacher.rb**

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom
end
```

**model/classroom.rb**

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :teacher
end
```

**app/admin/teacher.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Teacher do
      permit_params{
        :id
        :classroom_id
        :name
      }
end
```

Comment: Can you show your view and controller please?

Comment: Due to activeadmin, there is no controller or view. I am using the default view generated. There is only the permit params in app/admin/teacher.rb file so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forget comas in permit_params :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Teacher do
  permit_params{
    :id,
    :classroom_id,
    :name
  }
end
```

Comment: I removed the {} and added commas, this the fixed issue. thanks